# pmdarima.arima auto_arima function Model.fit giving LinAlgError error

Tags: python-3.x, pmdarima

I am doing a rolling forecast by building multiple sarima models in loop. When I run the code, it works well for many input but breaks down at some particular point providing LinAlgError: Schur decomposition solver error. The code providing Error is:

`model_sarima_oneyr = model_sarima_oneyr.fit(training_set_y, seasonal=True, m=7)`

I want to run code while skipping the error line (maybe just ignore the error), or if there is a matrix inversion error go to the alternate model, in which this kind of issue does not occur.

> The error most likely has occurred due to [method='lbfgsb'](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html#:%7E:text=Auto-ARIMA%20works%20by%20conducting,max_p%20%2C%20start_q%20%2C%20max_q%20ra); could I use another method which does not require matrix inversion and so no error?